# React Native Salesforce Marketing Cloud Sdk ios App crash Error

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have integrated `react-native-marketingcloudsdk` with my react native project.

Android integration was successful. Foreground Notifications are working fine. But Background and quit notifications are not received and listeners are not listening to the incoming notifications.

With iOS integration, the app crashed after a successful build.

Throwing below error...

"react-native": "0.68.2",
"react-native-marketingcloudsdk": "^8.0.0",

[image]

Comment: Seems like an error from the SDK. Have you searched to see if they have an issue open on their repository?

Comment: is there any documentation link about the sdk you mentioned: react-native-marketingcloudsdk ?

Comment: I used the github link - https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk